# MySql: Stored procedure syntax error due to Exception command

Tags: mysql, exception, stored-procedures, syntax-error

```
CREATE or replace procedure `isEven`(IN num int,OUT result varchar(6)) is
BEGIN
    set result=(select IF(MOD(num,2)=0,"Even","Odd"));
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ("Error!");
END isEven;
```

I am trying to make a stored procedure but there is an error in my code I can't understand what is the issue in this code.
Can anyone let me the correct syntax of the exception?

Comment: Looks like you try to mix MySQL syntax with Oracle syntax. That won't work of course...

Comment: @stickybit is right.  You must rewrite stored code when you move it from one make of dbms to another. Sad but true.